# Dockerfile not making RUN changes after FROM

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

So I have a docker file like this:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install php5-mysql
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN service apache2 restart
```

and then a docker-compose like this

```
version: '2'

services:
  apachephp:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '8081:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - '~/dev/test/backend:/var/www/html'
```

and everything works just fine, except the php-mysql plugin and the rewrite apache module.

Any idea of how on earth can I make this thing work?

Thanks.-

Comment: how do you know the commands don't work?

Comment: the php plugin does not shows in the phpinfo
and the rewrite is certainly not working
if I ssh to the container and run the commands it works :(

Answer (score 0):

If you change the base image, you need explicitly rebuild an image and recreate a container.

```
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose stop
$ docker-compose rm
$ docker-compose up
```